# 1 Token is not getting stored in my array

Tags: arrays, parsing, ascii, stringtokenizer

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

char *Data1[100];
char *operators[20];
char *identifiers[20][20];
int *ascii[100] = {0};
int ascii2[100] = {0};
unsigned int Tcount = 0;
unsigned int i;

int main(void)
{
    char *text = (char*)malloc ( 100 *sizeof( char));
    cout << "Enter the first arrangement of data." << endl;
    cin.getline(text, 100);
    char *token = strtok(text, " ");
    while ( token != NULL )
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        Data1[Tcount] = token;
        cout<< Data1[Tcount] << endl;
        Tcount++;

    }
    for(i=0; i < Tcount; i++)
    {

        ascii[i] = (int)Data1[i];
```

// cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information error

```
        cout << ascii[i] << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am first trying to store tokens in an array called 'Data1'. When doing this i enter in the data 'X = A + 1' into the user input. For some reason the first token(X) does not get stored in the array so my first question is how i could fix this.
Secondly, I am trying to use these tokens stored in the array and convert them into ASCII so they can be used for parsing. I am getting an error "cast from pointer to smaller type 'int' loses information" 
I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix these problems, especially the first one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
char data = (char)malloc ( 100*sizeof( char));   
while ( token != NULL )   
{   
   data[Tcount++] = *token;  
   token = strtok(NULL, " ");  
   for(i=0; i < (Tcount*2); i++)  
   {  
   ascii[i] = (int)data[i];   
   }  
 }   
for(i=0; i < (Tcount); i++)  
 {  
    cout << ascii[i] << endl;  
 }   
return 0;   
}
```